# ckeditor django no error but don't show editor

Tags: python, django, ckeditor

I trial make editor for my blog django when used django_summernote work good but when
ckeditor django no error but don't show editor so how fix it

forms.py
when used SummernoteInplaceWidget show but when used CKEditorWidget don't show and textarea input hiden

```
from django_summernote.widgets import SummernoteWidget, SummernoteInplaceWidget
from ckeditor.widgets import CKEditorWidget

class NewTopicForm(forms.ModelForm):

    # content = forms.CharField(widget=SummernoteInplaceWidget())
    content = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['author'].widget.attrs.update(
            {'class': 'd-none'})

        self.fields['author'].label = ''
        self.fields['author'].required = False
        self.fields['slug'].required = False

    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = ('title','image', 'author', 'content','NotfFaV','slug')
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'ml-3 mb-3 form-control border-0 read-more rounded-0', 'rows': '1', 'placeholder': 'اضف تعلق'}),
        }
```

urls.py

```
path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
```

views.py

```
def home(request):

    topic_form = NewTopicForm()

    return render(request, 'forum/home.html', { 'topic_form': topic_form })
```

home.html

```
    {{topic_form.media}}
    {{topic_form.content}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove from settings.py that or change path

```
CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = "/my_static/ckeditor/ckeditor/"
```